# Installing .Net Framework 4.6 on 1 server in a SharePoint 2013 farm

Tags: 2013, .net, server-farm, update

There is a SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 application servers and 3 web servers. For an assessment i need to install tooling that requires .Net Framework 4.6 (or higher). Currently .Net Framework 4.5.2 is installed.

To limit the extent of modifications required on the farm i was wondering:

- Is it possible to install .Net Framework 4.6 on only 1 server in a SharePoint 2031 farm?
- Should all servers in a SharePoint farm have the same .Net Framework level installed?
- Is it pobbisle to have a side by side installation of .Net Framework 4.6 and 4.5?
- Are there any issues with installing an .Net Framework update that i should be aware of?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can definitely install .NET Framework >= min supported by SharePoint 2013. I guess that SharePoint (I mean the distributive itself) just targeted on its min supported version and not bother if it will be higher. Here is more, frequently happens, that just with updates comes version of .NET higher. But I wouldn't recommend installing newer .NET just on one server, better do this on the whole farm.

> Is it possible to have a side by side installation of .Net Framework
>   4.6 and 4.5?

- AFAIK if you have installed v4.6 it will supersede the v4.5 so you don't need this, and in the .NET apps, if you run one on the server, you can still use any v4.5+ <= installed on the server.

Also keep in mind, that MS have a [minimal supported version of .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework) (currently v4.5.2), so better to keep an eye on this as well.